# Are there any command to see how processes are working?

Tags: command-line, process

I'm very new to Ubuntu. If I do this sort of command say:

```
cp file1 file2
```

The shell creates a child process and that child process will call `cp`, which in turn call `exec` system call of operating system.

Are there any command to visualize this process from my terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like `strace` traces the system calls, you can use `ltrace` to trace library calls.

Answer (score 6):

`strace` will show system calls made by a process. It won't give you an instruction-by-instruction view of what happens, but it will give the calls into the kernel performed.