# how to see the PID for currently running command?

Tags: command-line, gnome

while reading about linux I got :

> By default, variables created within a script are only available to
>   the current shell; child processes (sub-shells) will not have access
>   to values that have been set or modified. Allowing child processes to
>   see the values, requires use of the export command.

I tried to find about subshells then I came across [Are there any command to see how processes are working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184986/are-there-any-command-to-see-how-processes-are-working), and I found ltrace could be used for that, when I searched for how to use `ltrace` or `strace`, I found that `PID` is required attribute for that.

now, If I want to know the PID for `$ cp file1 file2` ,how would I do that??
so that I can use `ltrace` to it??

Comment: Where did you find that you need the PID of a process for ltrace or strace? afact the proper use is `ltrace command_to_trace` or `strace command_to_trace`.

Comment: @Seth, the last option of this http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2005/10/22/using-ltrace-to-trace-library-calls/

Comment: Thanx @seth,, it worked ..it is ltrace cp file1 file2,,

Comment: well just for curiosity how will I know the PID for command I am running on my shell??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### PID of current command

The PID of a command in your own shell is shown when you start the command in background. If the current command runs in the foreground, the shell mostly waits for it to finish, we have to wait too - except we want to use a tool outside this shell; See below for that option.

As an example command, I'll use this `ping` that sends a request every 5 seconds for 10 times:

```
ping -i 5 -c 10 example.com
```

Now, I'll use `&` to run it in the background:

```
$ ping -i 5 -c 10 example.com &
[1] 12238
$ PING example.com (93.184.216.119) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 93.184.216.119: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=118 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.216.119: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=117 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.216.119: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=117 ms
```

The `[1] 12238` tells us that the process has the process id, short PID 12238; And that it's the first background job currently running in this shell.

### Example: tracing library calls

In the same terminal we get the output of `ping`, so we better run ltrace in another one (`ping` has special root permissions, so we need `sudo` to mess with its inside):

```
$ sudo ltrace -p 12238      
[sudo] password for siegel: 
gettimeofday(0x7fff7f0b6900, 0)                                           = 0
gettimeofday(0x7fff7f0b68e0, 0)                                           = 0
sendmsg(3, 0x60a300, 2048, 24)                                            = 64
recvmsg(3, 0x7fff7f0b6970, 0, 0)                                          = 84
__printf_chk(1, 0x40813b, 64, 0x60a560)                                   = 29
__printf_chk(1, 0x4077ea, 4, 28)                                          = 11
__printf_chk(1, 0x40814d, 55, 11)                                         = 7
__printf_chk(1, 0x408162, 118, 7)                                         = 12
_IO_putc('\n', 0x7f7836d89400)                                            = 10
fflush(0x7f7836d89400)                                                    = 0
gettimeofday(0x7fff7f0b6900, 0)                                           = 0
poll(0x7fff7f0b6950, 1, 4880, 0)                                          = 0
gettimeofday(0x7fff7f0b6900, 0)                                           = 0
gettimeofday(0x7fff7f0b68e0, 0)                                           = 0
sendmsg(3, 0x60a300, 2048, 24)                                            = 64
recvmsg(3, 0x7fff7f0b6970, 0, 0)                                          = 84
__printf_chk(1, 0x40813b, 64, 0x60a560)                                   = 29
__printf_chk(1, 0x4077ea, 5, 28)                                          = 11
__printf_chk(1, 0x40814d, 55, 11)                                         = 7
__printf_chk(1, 0x408162, 118, 7)                                         = 12
_IO_putc('\n', 0x7f7836d89400)                                            = 10
fflush(0x7f7836d89400)                                                    = 0
gettimeofday(0x7fff7f0b6900, 0)                                           = 0
poll(0x7fff7f0b6950, 1, 4881, 0)
```

That's a trace of the library calls during two 'pings'.

### Finding PIDs of running processes in general

As the title question is not very specific, here are some other ways to find PIDs of currently running commands:

- Search for processes by command name
  `pgrep -x cmd`
  Note that the variant `pgrep cmd` is wrong: it mathes as substring
- Search by command line with arguments
  `pgrep -f cmdarg`
- List processes that belong to the current shell (session), like background processes, or the shell itself
  `ps -s $$`
- List all processes: "process status"
  `ps aux`
- Listing processes in a more interactive way: "table of processes"
  `top`
- And all you need at once: a table of processes, integrated with `ltrace` and `strace`:
  `htop`
  It's a variant of `top` with enhanced UI and configurability, plus some extras:
  Choose a process with the cursor line, and press <kbd>L</kbd> for `ltrace`, or <kbd>s</kbd> for `strace`!

Comment: I like using `top`, personally.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat Thank you for the hint - it made me notice that there is a perfect jack of all trades device for this question, `htop`.

Answer (score 1):

`bash`, `dash` (and many other shells) have built-in commands for job control. If you run a command in the background

```
sleep 9999 &
```

you can discover all the background commands of the current shell:

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 9999 &
```

If you need the process ID of one of them, you can get it with `jobs -p %N`, where `N` is the job ID in the job list (first column) above. There's also a special variable `$!` that the shell will substitute with the PID of the command executed in the background most recently.

For details and more options, have a look at the relevant section of the manuals of [`bash(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html) ([direct link to job control section in HTML version](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html)), [`dash(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dash.1.html) or your shell of choice. TLDP has a great [section on job control](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html) as well.